# Unable to install webdriver agent using XCode>>Product >Test :- Test failed stating Cannot link directly with dylib/framework,your binary

Tags: xcode, appium, xcode14

Hello forum i have come across a below can someone please help me to get this fix Issue :- I am facing this issue when i test the webdriver agent runner app using xcode . I have connected the IPAD and its even displayed in xocde. However if build the webdriver agnet xcode project from Product>>Build with integration app . Build is successful.

Error details under webdriverAgentLib:-
1- Cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of applications/xcode.app/contents/Developer/Platforms/IphoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XCTAutomationSupport.framework/XCTSupport for architecture arm64.

2- Linker command failed with exit code1(Use -v see Invocation)

Platform Details :-
Xcode :- 14.3.2 and 15.0.1
Appium version :- 1.22.1 even same with Appium 2
npm version :- 10.2.4

[image]
Please help as i got stuck and not able to proceed.